# Setting onclick listener and dialog listener to a dynamically created row in a table layout

Tags: android

I want to add a onClick Listener to a dynamically created table row in tablelayout. and onClick a alert dialog with two items 'edit', 'delete' and when i click edit it has to take all the items in the row i.e date, description, amount and start another activity which has Edittexts which should have this three items in them respectively. and when click delete that row should be deleted from there.....
thanks in advance.
please consider the code in comments..
I didnt know how do it so i have tried toast to know whether the items are retrived corectly, but no matter on which row i click only the last row is retrived

```
                                                                                                              MyDBHandler dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this);
              TableLayout tableLayout=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);
              SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getReadableDatabase();
                    // Start the transaction.
                   db.beginTransaction();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT date,description,amount FROM expdetails E `enter code here`WHERE E.date == date('now')";
         Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        //lpw.setAdapter(adapter);


    if(cursor.getCount() >0)
    {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            // Read columns data
            _date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"));
            _desc = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("description"));
            _amt = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("amount"));

            // dara rows
            row = new TableRow(this);
            row.setLayoutParams(new   `enter code here` `enter code here`TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

            String[] colText = {_date , _desc, _amt+""};
            //colText[0]=_date;
            //colText[1]=_desc;
            //colText[2]=_amt;
            for (String text : colText) {

                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setLayoutParams(new `enter code here`TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                tv.setTextSize(18);
                tv.setPadding(30, 10, 30, 10);
                tv.setText(text);
                row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                row.addView(tv);


               // row.setOnClickListener(rowOnClick);
                //row.getChildAt(0)
               /* row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        TextView tv1 =(TextView) row.getChildAt(0);
                        TextView tv2 = (TextView)row.getChildAt(1);
                         `enter code    here`Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),tv2.getText().toString(), `enter code here`Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //showDialog(DIALOG_ID);


                    }
                });*/
            }
            tableLayout.addView(row);

    }

                }
   cursor.close();

    db.endTransaction();
}
 /*private View.OnClickListener rowOnClick = new       `enter code here`View.OnClickListener()   {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Highlight selected row
        `enter code here`       `enter code here`   `enter code here`//v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_lig`enter code here`ht));
        final int k = v.getId();
        Toast.makeText(ExpenseDetails.this, colText[k],
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};*/
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_ID:

        ArrayList<String> ops = new ArrayList<>();
        //lpw=new ListPopupWindow(this);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, `enter code  here`        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, ops);
        ops.add("Edit");
        ops.add("Delete");
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);


        builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // The 'which' argument contains the index position
                // of the selected item
                TextView tv1 =(TextView) row.getChildAt(0);
                TextView tv2 = (TextView)row.getChildAt(1);

                switch (which) {
                    case 0:

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), `enter code         here`tv1.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), `enter code       here`tv2.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        break;

                }
            }
        });
        return builder.create();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: here is the code. I have just tested the onclick ation...if possible consider the comments also..

Answer (score 0):

1. Associate a click listener in the table row
2. Pass the table row id in the bundle and start the new activity with the respective editText views , take the user input and notify the row element of the table with the new values

Comment: can you explain this with an example

Answer (score 0):

```
While you create a table Row dynamically associate an Id with it and in onclick listener distinguish the row pressed with it's id

eg 
TableLayout tl=new TableLayout(context);
for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
TableRow tr = new TableRow(context);
tr.setId(i);
tr.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View view)
{

switch(view.getId())
{
case 1: 
doSomething();
break;
case 2: 
doSomething();
}

}

public void doSomething()
{

}


Similarly do it for a dialog
```

Comment: each row has 3 columns but i am geting the most recent row...no matter where click and that to only one column

Comment: Did you add a view ID and in onclick separated the viewID